# GKE Service with standalone NEG keeps showing failed healthcheck

Tags: gke-networking

I have a simple "Hello world" Deployment, with a Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-kube
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"exposed_ports": {"80":{}}}'
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: hello-kube
```

The deployment works fine, and the NEG is created, but when I check in the Web Console the actual endpoint (which uses a virtual Pod IP address correctly) is shown as unhealthy. When I check with an interactive "ubuntu" Pod, I can curl without problems. Also if I try a VM in the network (the same VPC as the cluster is on) I get a "Hello world!".

I did add the firewall rule to allow health checks, but that rule naturally either mentions the tags of the cluster nodes, or else something like "all on this network". However, are the aliased IPs also on the network? Could it be the health check fails because I cannot add a rule that allows network traffic to the virtual IPs?

At this moment I cannot get the NEG to work for me... Anyone have an idea?

Bert Laverman

Comment: Could you elaborate? How did you create neg? Do you want to get to this service only from cluster or also outside? Could you provide some logs for troubleshoot?

Comment: @PjoterS The "cloud.google.com/neg" annotation will cause an automagically created NEG, and the purpose is indeed to allow you to use it to reach the Service from outside the GKE cluster.

Answer (score 3):

So the answer appeared both simple and confusing: The NEG is created as a consequence of a correctly annotated Service, but the service is then unused. The NEG will be defined using the IP address of the Pod (this only works for Clusters with IP aliasing enabled). For me, any attempt to set up the Load Balancer and Backend Service on the basis of the Service specs failed. It will work if you see the Service as the vehicle for publication, but don't try to remap ports.

So you should:

- Set up the Pod/Deployment with a port as you want
- Define the Service with the annotation, but just keep the ports equal:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-kube
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"exposed_ports": {"80":{}}}'
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: hello-kube
```

This will give you a NEG that you can add to a Backend Service, but you can still get mixed up if you don't create the correct health-check. The simplest way actually is:

```
gcloud compute health-checks create http http-basic-check --use-serving-port
```

This will give you a generic HTTP healthcheck, that depends on the NEG/Instance Group to specify the port. Then create the Backend Service like this:

```
gcloud compute backend-services create magic-backend --protocol HTTP --health-checks http-basic-check --global
```

This Backend Service you can immediately add to your LoadBalancer and that won't change. The NEGs need to be added/removed depending on your Service deployments. The NEG will get Pod updates (scaling, migrating, etc) automatically. You can use the "AutoNEG controller" (See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-autoneg-controller) to automate the adding/removing of NEGs to the Backend Service. In the above example that means you need to add an annotation (after you install the controller):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-kube
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"exposed_ports": {"80":{}}}'
    anthos.cft.dev/autoneg: '{"name":"magic-backend", "max_rate_per_endpoint":1000}'
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: hello-kube
```